# Regular Expression for Use in Ant to Remove Version Number from File Name

Tags: regex, ant

I need a regular expression for use in Ant to remove the version number from file names (JARs specifically).  I have tried several of the suggestions found on SO and they work to a degree, but I have a few use cases I cannot get ironed out.  Here are my use cases...

1. name1-x.x.x.jar
2. name1-name2-x.x.x.jar
3. name1-name2-name3-x.x.x.jar
4. name1.jar
5. name1-name2.jar
6. name1-name2-name3.jar

Use cases 1, 2, 4, and 5 are the most common.  I am using the following regular expression (which I obtained from another post here on SO and tweaked just a bit), which works for use cases 1, 2, and 3, but not for 4, 5, and 6. I have been testing using this [site](http://myregexp.com/).

```
^([a-z].+)*-[0-9]*.*\.jar$
```

I spent a couple of hours the other day trying to get this to work for use cases 4, 5, and 6, but had zero luck. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!!

**EDIT 10.12.2015**

The accepted answer worked very well as it provided the minimum result needed. In other words, if the JAR file name did not match the pattern, then nothing was returned, meaning the file name can be used as-is (the `defaultValue` of ant-contrib's `propertyregex`). I wound up using it like this (as a test)...

```
    <basename property="jar.name" file="D:\SomeDir\Tomcat7\lib\commons-httpcore-4.4.2.jar"/> <!-- this would be the file name being deployed - ideally passed in as a property to a target -->

    <propertyregex property="jar.base.name" override="true"
          input="${jar.name}"
          regexp="^(.*)-\d+\.\d+\.\d+(\.jar)$"
          replace="\1*.jar"
          casesensitive="false" 
          defaultValue="${jar.name}"/>

    <echo message="Backing up/undeploying '${jar.name}' from Tomcat..." level="info"/>
    <echo message="Base JAR name is: '${jar.base.name}'" level="info"/>
    <!-- this will result in commons-httpcore*.jar -->

    <fileset id="target.file" dir="D:\SomeDir\Tomcat7\lib" includes="**/${jar.base.name}"/>

    <condition property="target.file.found" value="true" else="false">
        <resourcecount refid="target.file" when="greater" count="0"/>
    </condition>
    <echo message="File to be backed up found? '${target.file.found}'"/>
```

Obviously I will do more with this than what is shown in my example above, but hopefully what I have included above helps others in the implementation of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should do the trick:

```
(.*)-\d+\.\d+\.\d+(\.jar)$
```

Explanation:

`(.*)` initially matches the entire file name. The `-\d+\.\d+\.\d+(\.jar)$` then causes the regex to backtrack to see if it can match `-x.x.x.jar` at the end of the file name.

`\d+` matches digits.

The leading part of the file name is captured in `\1`. `.jar` is captured in `\2`.

If a file name doesn't end with `-x.x.x.jar`, then the regex won't match and the file name will be left untouched.